# How to set/adjust Precision for an iterative calculation?

Tags: polynomials, precision-and-accuracy

How should I restructure this code?  I generate a high-order polynomial `poly` with integer coefficients, then find roots and divide them out of poly one at a time.  I want FindRoot[] to use a very high precision on the first pass but then just use the precision of the inputs afterward.

```
z[n_, c_] := If[n > 0, z[n - 1, c]^2 + c, c];
poly = PolynomialQuotient[z[10, c] - z[6, c], 1 + c^2, c];
rts = {};
Do[Print[Precision[poly]];
 aa = FindRoot[poly, {c, I}, WorkingPrecision -> Min[500, Floor[Precision[poly]]]];
 AppendTo[rts, c /. aa];
 poly = PolynomialQuotient[poly, ((z - c)*(z - Conjugate[c]) /. aa) /. z -> c, c], {j, 1, 5}]
```

(* [Infinity]  319.649  135.906  0.00598703 *)

I'm losing so much precision on each pass that I can only get a few roots.  I'm trying to get the roots closest to i without having to find all the roots.  I encountered this precision problem while trying to fix this [other problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104795/finding-all-complex-polynomial-roots-in-a-specified-range-efficiently/104865).  I'm also not clear on WHY the polynomial division loses precision so quickly.

Comment: Why are you using `PolynomialQuotient`, which drops remainders?  When I replaced it by a simple divide inside the loop, it worked fine.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  If the roots are correct, the remainders should be zero.

Comment: What you say is correct.  Nonetheless, the precision remains at 500 and the error messages stop, if the second instance of  `PolynomialQuotient` is replaced by divide.  Also, replacing `c` by `d + I` might help.  Incidentally, a `WorkingPrecision` of 190 gives the same results as 500, but 180 does not work.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  Any idea why PQ loses so much precision?

Comment: No, I do not.  Can you provide a problem that requires only, say, a `WorkingPrecision` of 50 but still captures this strange behavior?  It might be easier to analyze in detail.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  I haven't found any.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  But your suggestion about using a regular divide instead of PQ seems to have fixed the problem.  If you want to drop that into an Answer I can Accept it.

Comment: Thanks. A brief answer is provided.

Comment: Could try `PolynomialReduce` and see if that behaves better for this purpose.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  Well that took about 10 min to return a result, but I guess 500 sigfigs on 1024 coefficients takes a bit of doing.  What is PR doing differently to retain precision that PQ doesn't?

Comment: Offhand I don't know. I'm pretty sure it's not using fixed precision arithmetic though.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  If you're interested, I pitted the three methods against each other in a Timing/Precision test in the Answer below.

Comment: Also there is the possibility of setting `$MinPrecision` in a `Block` when invoking `PolynomialQuotient`. An undocumented shortcut is to use `NumericalMath`FixedPrecisionEvaluate[expr,prec]`. I'll show an example where I work directly with coefficient lists in finding the quotient.

Comment: Ah, I know the bottleneck. It is converting to rationals and using very slow exact arithmetic. Can do better as follows. `poly = NumericalMath`FixedPrecisionEvaluate[
    PolynomialReduce[poly, fac, c, 
     CoefficientDomain -> InexactNumbers], prec][[1, 1]];`. The evaluation in fixed precision is needed to stanch the otherwise huge precision loss. See remarks in my posted response for how-to's on detection/correction of precision ills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precision is preserved, and error messages are eliminated by replacing the second instance of `PolynomialQuotient` by a simple divide.

```
poly = poly/ (((z - c)*(z - Conjugate[c]) /. aa) /. z -> c)
```

The only apparent difference is that `PolynomialQuotient` discards any remainder, and there is a remainder unless `c` is exact.  In some way that I do not understand, discarding the remainder must reduce the precision of `poly`.  So, this may not be a particularly satisfying answer, but it does produce accurate roots for a `WorkingPrecision` as low as `Min[190, Floor[Precision[poly]]]`.  Replace `190` by `187`, however, and the precision of `poly` gradually decreases to `185`, whereupon the Jacobian becomes singular.  For completeness, rts[[5]] for `190` is

```
(* -0.01660571703737496762392836921351877966202681662442570475568531876233767935059224313655985208958046768635767201058325661435694155300994327878649425388424142524075655339495830479365786600752927
 + 1.006001836522824948881217257805018657146542248017733702434346228688166066459126472333560301933200993465308529209500537579261396301606919993043401875320490162101139793328283528897296023734789 I *)
```

Comment: Thanks!  The loss of precision with PolynomialQuotient was surprising, but I suppose it shouldn't be given the number of division problems involved.

Comment: I pitted the three methods against each other in a Timing/Precision test in the Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Follow-up from OP:
Based on the very helpful Answers and comments above from @bbgodfrey and @Daniel Lichtblau, I ran the following test, comparing the three methods on speed and precision:

```
z[n_, c_] := If[n > 0, z[n - 1, c]^2 + c, c];
polyOrig = PolynomialQuotient[z[10, c] - z[6, c], 1 + c^2, c];
rtsPR = {}; rtsDiv = {}; rtsPQ = {};
nRoots = 3;
Do[
 poly = polyOrig;
 Print[Timing[
   Do[Print[Precision[poly]];
    aa = FindRoot[poly, {c, I}, WorkingPrecision -> Max[10, Min[300, Floor[Precision[poly]]]]];
    fac = (((z - c)*(z - Conjugate[c]) /. aa) /. z -> c);
    Which[
     pass == 1,
     AppendTo[rtsPR, c /. aa];
     poly = PolynomialReduce[poly, fac, c][[1, 1]],
     pass == 2,
     AppendTo[rtsPQ, c /. aa];
     poly = PolynomialQuotient[poly, fac, c],
     pass == 3,
     AppendTo[rtsDiv, c /. aa];
     poly = poly/fac], {i, 1, nRoots}]]], {pass, 1, 3}]
```

Output:
(*
[Infinity]

300.

300.

{525.989,Null}

[Infinity]

119.649

0.00743297

FindRoot::precw: The precision of the argument function (<<75>>+<<967>>) is less than WorkingPrecision (10.`). >>

{0.967206,Null}

[Infinity]

300.

300.

{7.16045,Null}
*)

Verdict:
PolynomialReduce retains precision but is slow,
PolynomialQuotient loses precision very quickly,
Divide is fast and precise but leaves you with a potential 0/0 problem.

Does anyone see anything else in these results I didn't, or have an idea for an improvement?

Answer (score 1):

As promised in a comment, here is a variant that works in fixed precision. We do get three good roots below.

First some code to do quotients of polynomials represented by their coefficient lists. This was taken from internal code for `PolynomialSmithDecomposition` in some Control Theory context. (I'm allowed to do that, it was my code and written on a weekend.)

```
lpQuoRem[p1_, p2_] := 
 Module[{p2top = p2[[-1]], top, quo, quolist, rem = p1, len, max}, 
  top = Length[p1] - Length[p2] + 1;
  If[top <= 0, Return[{{}, rem}]];
  quolist = ConstantArray[0, top];
  While[Length[rem] >= Length[p2], max = Max[Abs[p1]];
   quo = rem[[-1]]/p2top;
   quolist[[Length[rem] - Length[p2] + 1]] = quo;
   rem = Most[rem] - quo*PadLeft[Most[p2], Length[rem] - 1];
   len = Length[rem];
   While[len > 0 && rem[[len]] == 0, len--];
   rem = Take[rem, len];];
  {quolist, rem}]

z[n_, c_] := If[n > 0, z[n - 1, c]^2 + c, c];
polyOrig = PolynomialQuotient[z[10, c] - z[6, c], 1 + c^2, c];
rtsPR = {};
nRoots = 3;
prec = 300;
poly = polyOrig;
Do[
  Print[Timing[
     Print[{Precision[poly], Exponent[poly, c]}];
     aa = 
      FindRoot[poly, {c, I}, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 
        Max[10, Min[300, Floor[Precision[poly]]]]];
     fac = {c*Conjugate[c], -(c + Conjugate[c]), 1} /. aa;
     Print[N@{aa, fac}];
     AppendTo[rtsPR, c /. aa];
     lpoly = CoefficientList[poly, c];
     lpoly = 
      NumericalMath`FixedPrecisionEvaluate[lpQuoRem[lpoly, fac], prec];
     poly = Expand[FromDigits[Reverse[lpoly[[1]]], c]];
     ]];
  , {i, 1, nRoots}];

(* {\[Infinity],1022}

{{c->-0.000732220309309+1.00453713135 I},{1.00909538441 +0. I,0.00146444061862 +0. I,1.}}

{0.908594,Null}

{300.,1020}

{{c->-0.00956676851273+1.00673513946 I},{1.01360716408 +0. I,0.0191335370255 +0. I,1.}}

{1.250491,Null}

{300.,1018}

{{c->0.00279929953246 +1.00502058481 I},{1.01007421197 +0. I,-0.00559859906491+0. I,1.}}

{1.548567,Null} *)
```

Caveat: There is the possibility that eventually an accumulation of error will cause the results to be bad in the sense of not being roots to the original polynomial. A production environment would check for that and maybe raise precision when necessary. This does not require a full restart. One just polishes the "good" roots with `FindRoot` to higher precision than were earlier obtained, and redoes the quotients at higher precision.

Comment: What exactly is ``NumericalMath`FixedPrecisionEvaluate``?  Is it intended to be used as a magical function that cures all numerical instabilities?

Comment: It's what its name suggests: evaluate numerically in fixed precision. It disables the precision tracking that is used by default. There is no cure for all numeric instabilities. Evaluation at high precision can sometimes help handle ill-conditioning.

Comment: When does the user-defined `lpQuoRem[p1, p2]` perform better that the built-in `CoefficientList[PolynomialQuotientRemainder[p1.\[FormalX]^Range[0,Length[p1]-1],p2.\[FormalX]^Range[0,Length[p2]-1],\[FormalX]],\[FormalX]]`?

Comment: @user688486 I’m not sure offhand. I would need to look at how PolynomialQuotientRemainder handles fixed precision. Since it’s the same code as used in PolynomialQuotient, and given that that did not seem to give good results, I will guess that lpQuoRem will come out ahead. But really it requires testing to be sure.