# How to Count the number of roots in the Domain from an equation

Tags: equation-solving

How do i `Count[]` the number of roots in the Domain and printout the intervals in `x` containing these roots.

Given the function

```
f[x_] := (1/x) Sin[ x]
```

and the Domain

```
{x, -2.5 Pi, 2.5 Pi}
```

Comment: `Solve[]` and `NSolve[]` can solve equations with constraints like `f[x] == 0 && -2.5 Pi <= x <= 2.5 Pi`.  In such an approach `Length[]` will be easier to use than `Count[]`.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5663)?

Comment: I'm afraid not yet. will check it out. thank you @J.M.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Why not just use `CountRoots[f[x], {x, -2.5*Pi, 2.5*Pi}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FindInstance](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) to *Find several instances:*

```
FindInstance[f[x] == 0 && -2.5 Pi < x < 2.5 Pi, x, 4]
```

> {{x->-6.28319},{x->-3.14159},{x->-6.28319},{x->3.14159}}

or some others:

```
Reduce[f[x] == 0 && -2.5 Pi < x < 2.5 Pi, x]
```

> x==-6.28319||x==-3.14159||x==3.14159||x==6.28319

using [Length](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html), as suggested by @Michael E2

```
Length[%]
```

> 4

```
sol = NSolve[{f[x] == 0, -2.5 Pi < x < 2.5 Pi}, x]
```

> {{x->-6.28319},{x->-3.14159},{x->3.14159},{x->6.28319}}

```
Length[%]
```

> 4

```
points = {x, f[x]} /. sol // Chop
```

> {{-6.28319, 0}, {-3.14159, 0}, {3.14159, 0}, {6.28319, 0}}

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -2.5 Pi, 2.5 Pi}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@points}]
```

[image]

You can show the Intervals like so:

```
NumberLinePlot[f[x] == 0, {x, -2.5 Pi, 2.5 Pi}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'll address only the root counting portion. In [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1967-0228165-4), Delves and Lyness present a method based on contour integration for counting all the *complex* roots of a function within a given contour. In your specific case, it goes like this:

```
Round[Chop[NIntegrate[f'[z]/f[z], {z, -5 π/2, -5 π I/2, 5 π/2, 5 π I/2, -5 π/2}]/(2 π I)]]
   4
```

where I used an anticlockwise square contour with two corners on the endpoints of interest. Luckily, the function is known to have only real roots, so the count obtained is accurate. For more complicated functions, a different contour might be needed.

Comment: So glad you posted this. Now I can just upvote and don't have to think about coding it.

Comment: @Daniel, I'll admit I haven't yet gotten to actually implementing the full Delves-Lyness; it's surprisingly tricky to make something reliable out of it. Thanks.

Comment: Here is [some related code](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math.symbolic/xSMHxTm3z00/Mst_vMsJiMgJ) I was able to dredge up, also far from complete. My general feeling is it is better to subdivide than to try to go the "find polynomial with same roots" route.

Comment: Okay, I finally found the [related MSE post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105001/51) I was looking for. Not perfect but the approach can be effective.

Comment: Heh, interesting. I sent you an e-mail in the meantime.